# How to correctly display trees in ArcScene?

Tags: arcscene

The first image is a screenshot of the view in ArcScene.  I am trying to export this scene to a tif or jpg.  The scene is composed of the following layers:

- A raster
- Three polygon layers displayed as outlines only
- One transparent polygon layer
- A point layer displayed as trees based on height values within the point attribute table.

When I export the scene to a jpg or tif, the resulting error image is shown below with the gray overlay.  I was able to isolate the problem though--it appears the export works for everything except the points (displayed as trees).  If I export the scene with the points not displayed as tree, this also works.  Where am I going wrong?  How can I resolve the issue so that the trees are displayed correctly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jpeg doesn't do transparency.  Did you try exporting to PNG?

Comment: @KevinMayall Unfortunately, none of the formats seem to support transparent polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert polygons to lines.

Comment: +1 Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.  Thanks for the idea--it worked